# Supplemental JavaScript for Bokeh Plot

Tags: python, bokeh

Lets say I have a very simple Bokeh plot:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
p.line([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9])
```

The figure nicely produces HTML

```
html = p.__repr_html__()
```

What is all of the other stuff that I need in order to embed this in a web page?  I prefer to link out to externally hosted javascript rather than inlining everything.

My ideal answer is of the form "Just copy-paste these three lines:..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To embed a Bokeh plot in your webpage without having to inline the JS/CSS you can use `bokeh.embed.components` together with `bokeh.resources.CDN` as shown in the example below

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embedding.html#components

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import components

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

script, div = components(plot, CDN)
```

Take into consideration that *using these components assumes that BokehJS has already been loaded, for instance either inline in the document text, or from CDN.*

The CDN tags that you'll have to add in your html page to render the plots are, e.g. for bokeh version 0.8.2:

```
<link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.8.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.8.2.min.js">
```

Make sure that those links correspond to the version that you actually passed to components. You can get those links by doing:

```
In [1]: from bokeh.resources import CDN

In [2]: CDN.js_files
Out[2]: ['http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.8.2.min.js']

In [3]: CDN.css_files
Out[3]: ['http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.8.2.min.css']
```